# How to configure Nginx to listen on vNIC IP?

Tags: docker, nginx, containers, nginx-config

I am running a Nginx server on it with configuration like

```
server
{
 listen 1.2.3.4:8200;
 ...
}
```

But I get an error saying

```
nginx: [emerg] bind() to 1.2.3.4:8200 failed  
errorDetail": "99- Cannot assign requested address
```

But that is how I want my Nginx config to look. I have setup a VNic on my Linux docker container with inet address "1.2.3.4".

On searching through some links - looks like `You can't bind to an IP address not assigned to your computer.`, but this IP is assigned through vNIC!

Also I see this error only in Docker container setup though. Nginx config loads fine in my Azure Linux VM. Any setting that I might be missing in the docker setup?

I use docker-compose to create docker container, and my `dockerCompose.yaml` file looks something like this -

```
version: "3"
services:
  dev:
    image: <MyImageName>
    build:
      dockerfile: docker/Dockerfile-build
      context: .
    ports:
      - 8080:80
      - 8200:8200
      - "127.0.0.1:8083:22"
    working_dir: /azure
    entrypoint: /bin/bash
    cap_add:
      - NET_ADMIN
```

Comment: If it's running in a Docker container, it doesn't have direct access to any of the host interfaces.  It needs to `listen 0.0.0.0:8200`, and your `docker run -p` option can specify a specific host interface.

Comment: @DavidMaze I have created a virtual network interface inside the docker container.

Comment: How?  Usually you don't directly manage a container's network setup, you get whatever `docker run` gives you.  Can you edit the question to include the complete set of commands you're running to set up this environment?

Answer (score 0):

`netstat -ntlp` shows which process is holding the `IP:port`, so I just killed the process using the `IP:port`, and reloaded nginx.